# Does each model need a separate optimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x

This might be a stupid question, but let's say I want to train multiple models in parallel, do I need a separate optimizer for each or can I just reuse one for all models?

Comment: As models are different from each other, use 2 separate ones. E.g., `opt1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)` and `opt2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)`. If you have more models, then create as many as the number of your models.